# How to get gradle idea plugin to use USER_HOME environment variable when resolving dependencies

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

When I run

```
gradle idea
```

on my multiproject build, the iml and ipr files contain fully resolved directory paths to my dependencies.
For example:

```
<CLASSES>
    <root url="jar://C:/Users/myusername/.gradle/caches/artifacts-24/filestore/.../"/>
</CLASSES>
```

I would prefer that they use the USER_HOME env variable:

```
<CLASSES>
    <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/artifacts-24/filestore/.../"/>
</CLASSES>
```

Is this behavior expected? Ultimately I'd like to commit the iml and ipr into our source repo for other developers on my team to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend to check IDEA files in to source control. Instead, you could regenerate them whenever needed (after configuring the IDEA plugin according to your needs), or use the new Gradle plugin in IDEA 13 (EAP). But to answer your question, something like the following should work:

```
idea {
    pathVariables USER_HOME: file(System.getProperty("user.home"))
}
```

This will replace any occurrence of the file path on the right with the variable on the left. I'm not sure if `USER_HOME` is a built-in variable in IDEA. If not, you may have to set it from within IDEA. (You should be prompted when you open the project.)

For details on the Gradle build script API, check out the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).

Comment: The worrying thing to me when I read this solution is that the default Gradle's IDEA plugin is using *isn't* the value of user.home... so what are they using, if not that?